# Eclipse, Remote (SFTP) Editing and Backup Files

Tags: eclipse

Which Solution is the best, to work with remote files via SFTP in Eclipse and to get backupfiles (remote) on every save?

I've installed RSE, but I think it won't create backup files.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Please specify the operating system you're using Eclipse on

Comment: Nothing specific to php, retagging

Answer (score 0):

If you think of backup files as files like the one created by editors like vi (filename~ or so), then the simple answer is that Eclipse does not create these backup files (neither locally, nor remote)

If you think about the "local history" that eclipse keeps, that is stored in your workspace (in the .metadata) directory and thus always local. I don't know if one can use ECF to have a whole workspace remote, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used eclipse with RSE editing php scripts from an FTP server with very bad results, RSE was losing the connection with server very often. Then I tried Aptana Estudio (http://www.aptana.com/), an IDE based on eclipse, and it works great. I can edit php and javascript code with a very good code completion assistant. Its remote file browser works perfectly. I don't know if it has an option for saving backups of remote files but why not do you give it a try?.

Answer (score 0):

I use ant to sync my workspace to the web-server trough sftp.
I configured the ant build to do the following tasks:

1. Sync workspace to local temp folder
2. Create zip of temp folder
3. Send zip trough sftp to server
4. Call a custom unzip php script on server

The hole process only takes a few seconds even if you are on a not so fast network. Because you are only sending 1 small well compressed zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as you. I'm using eclipse and working on a remote server.

The best solution I found is using rsync. rsync is an amazing linux utility for syncronizing remote folders. It uses an algorithm that makes the whole process very very fast.

You can configure a custom builder into your project that launches the rsync every time your project is build (this could happen on every save).

http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=414